# How do i take an input in Python in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, netbeans, netbeans-8

When running python in netbeans, when I type in input, how and where do I take in input. eg

```
name = input("enter your name")
print("hello",name)
```

When I run this I get the output on the left in the shell but when I try and input anything in that window I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rahul\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NewPythonProject\src\newpythonproject.py", line 18, in <module>
    name = input("enter your name")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
```

I am using netbeans 8.2.

thanks!

Comment: Presumably this is actually Python 2.7 and you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: Or a better solution, since they are following Python3 guide, as it seems, they should install Python3, or actually, just the actual Python. At least that will be the case by 2020.

Comment: hi. python 3.6. ya have python installed, but wanted to use some ide so went with netbeans. might just change the ide . but the inputs are working with numbers not string. raw_input worked btw.

Comment: @dxVxb `raw_input` does not exist in 3.6. You are definitely using Python 2

Answer (score 0):

**If You use python version 2+**

```
name = raw_input("enter your name")
print("hello {}".format(name))
```

**If You use python version 3+**

```
name = input("enter your name")
print("hello {}".format(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `input()` in `Python 2`, it performs and `eval()` on the user input.

To get the exact string the user typed, you have to use `raw_input()` to get exactly what the user typed.

Also in `Python 2.7`, the `print` is a statement rather than a function. You can lose the parentheses.

your code will look like,

```
name = raw_input("enter your name")
print "hello", name
```